# different config file for each service reference in c#

Tags: c#, app-config, service-reference

I use many `web service references` in my `C#` project. So my `app.config` file has lots of service reference entries. Because of that, the config file looks so confusing.
I want to create `different config files` for my each service reference. For example; for `Service1` reference, I want to use `service1.config` file, for `Service2` reference `service2.config` and so on.
How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one `App.config` in a project.The app will use the config file named YourExcecutable.exe.config which is by default the file `App.config`. But you can have multipe configuration files and load then as you need using code. But you can't keep all of them loaded at the same time. you can only switch between the files as you need.

`SOLUTION 1`

You can use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) Class to load an alternate config file by code.

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap("path to new file"); 
System.Configuration.Configuration configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
```

`SOLUTION 2`

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", @"Config file path");
```

Comment: Isn't there any way of splitting app.config file into different files?

Comment: Can I load multiple config files by this approach?

Comment: @Fer at a time you can't have everything loaded. but in code you can switch between configuration files. There is NO WAY to load multiple configs at the same time. only option is to SWITCH as you need.

Comment: I understand that I can not load a different config file which has configuration settings of a service reference. So I need to put all configuration settings of all service references in one single config file which is App.config. That means my app.config file will remain being confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **appSettings.config** and store all of your relevant setting in there.

In your app.config you can reference this file like this :-

```
<appSettings file="_foldername\appSettings.config" />
```

Comment: Can I add multiple references like: `<appSettings file="service1.config" /><appSettings file="service2.config" />`

Comment: No, but at least this keeps your web.config clean and all of these settings in one spot.

Comment: It will not help me. But thanks anyway, I didn't know about referencing a config file from app.config.